# Remove filename but keep the path from grep result

Tags: bash, grep, git-bash

I got a list of files with my grip results.

```
$ grep -il 'name:red' */*/doc.txt
current_dir/Big_A/Folder1/doc.txt
current_dir/Big_A/Folder2/doc.txt
current_dir/Big_C/Folder5/doc.txt
```

I'd now like to move the entire folders that matched my result somewhere else and rename based on the contents in their doc file. While I had sucessfully grepped the name I want with

```
$ grep -i 'name:red' */*/doc.txt | cut -f2- -d:
Red Bucket
Red Asparagus
Red Blueberries
```

I'm drawing a blank on removing just the final filename so I can move entire folders.

I have tried some piping it with cut but can't find a working method that lets me cut on the correct position given that rev isn't supported in gitbash and `cut --output-delimiter=doc` did absoutely nothing.

Edit: 20 seconds after posting I found sed 's/search/replace' which solved the first half.

So this is the result I want.

```
current_dir/Mars/Red Bucket/doc.txt
current_dir/Mars/Red Asparagus/doc.txt
current_dir/Mars/Red Blueberries/doc.txt
```

Comment: Where does `Mars` come from? Can you predict that the top-level directory will always be `current_dir`? Please [edit] to clarify the requirements.

Comment: Maybe also notice that `grep -h` can be used to prevent `grep` from printing the file name when searching multiple files.

Comment: 'grep -h' can be used but it doesn't change too much. a 'grep-i' with cuts achieves same result. 

Mars was just a example folder to move the contents to. Maybe calling it Big_New would have been more logical. 

Yes. I'm gonna be working from 2 levels above the information files so ./*/*/doc.txt should always work. Temporarily im doing this in a Test folder so it's 1 level less (./*/doc.txt)

Comment: No, it doesn't change too much, but using a single process is always preferable to using two processes.  You could also use `grep -i 'name:red' */*/doc.txt | while IFS=':' filename newdest; do`... but then you have a problem if one file contains two matches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is rather unclear really. But something like this perhaps?

```sh
#!/bin/Bash
grep -il 'name:red' */*/doc.txt |
while IFS='' read -r matched; do
    folder=${matched%/*}
    newdest=$(grep -i -m1 'name:red' "$matched")
    echo mv ./"$folder" current_dir/Mars/"$newdest"
done
```

If this looks like what you wanted, remove the `echo` to make it actually run `mv`.

The reason `cut` doesn't work on a string is that it just allows for a single-character delimiter.  Here, we instead use the shell's built in [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) facility to trim the suffix from the file name.

We use `grep -m 1` to only print the first match in each file.  If you know there can only be one match in each file, you can take that out.  If you can specify a more constrained regex to make sure you only get one match, maybe use `sed` or Awk instead of `grep` to fetch the interesting part out of a longer pattern match.  For example,

```sh
    newdest=$(sed -n 's%.*<tag attrib="name:red">\([^<>]*\)</tag>.*%\1%p' "$matched")
```

to fetch the interesting string out of an XML-like tag structure. (Though processing XML with line-oriented regex tools is brittle and complex; if your input is really XML, maybe use a proper XML parser for this.)

Comment: After some minor modification to my personal filenames it almost worked. It pulled out all the doc.txt files, renamed them and put the first in a folder called doc.txt while the others are outside. So I got my old folders with their remaining content left where they came from.

Fixing the new doc.txt was easy but grabbing entire folders is being more troublesome

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "grabbing entire folders". Again, could you please edit the question to clarify what exactly you need and where exactly you are stuck?

Comment: Oh you want to move the entire folder, not just the matched file? See update now.